# cellForRowAtIndexpath method is not being called when I scroll the table fast

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have written some logic in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method in `UITableview`. When I scroll the `UITableView` quickly the method is not getting called.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
 {
    @try
    {

        NSLog(@"Cell no :%d",indexPath.row);

        if(requestMode)
        {
            NSLog(@"Request mode.");
            AlertBoxCell *cell=(AlertBoxCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InboxCell"];
            if(cell==nil)
                cell=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlertBoxCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

            UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] init];
            bgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            UIView* bgview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-2, -5, 235, 109)];

            slider=[self getSlider];
            BOOL emergencyType; // For show acceptedby info only for normal accepted alerts
            if ([alertCode[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"ALERT_EMERGENCY"]||[alertCode[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"HELP_EMERGENCY"])
            {
                cell.messageLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:25];


                NSMutableAttributedString *resultString;

                if(![senderName[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NA"])
                {

                    NSMutableAttributedString * content2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:senderName[indexPath.row] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:25]}];

                    NSMutableAttributedString * content3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@",allAlerts[indexPath.row]] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20]}];

                    resultString = [content2 mutableCopy];
                    [resultString appendAttributedString:content3];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSMutableAttributedString* content3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:allAlerts[indexPath.row] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:20] }];
                    resultString = [content3 mutableCopy];
                }


                cell.messageLabel.attributedText=resultString;


                emergencyType=YES;
                bgview1.layer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_alert.png"]CGImage];

                if([allAlertStatus[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"])
                {
                    slider.value=0.0;
                    slider.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
                }
                else
                    slider.value=1.1;
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 @"FranklinGothDemiCTT"
                 @"MyriadPro-Bold"
                 @"MyriadPro-Regular"
                 @"MyriadPro-Cond"
                 FranklinGothBookCTT
                 */

                cell.messageLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:20];

                //[cell.messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 7, 198, 88)];


                cell.messageLabel.text=allAlerts[indexPath.row];

                emergencyType=NO;
                if([allAlertStatus[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"])
                {
                    bgview1.layer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_alert.png"]CGImage];//yellow color
                    slider.value=0.0;
                    slider.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    bgview1.layer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_alert.png"]CGImage];
                    slider.value=1.0;
                }
                if([clearIds[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"])
                {
                    bgview1.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
                    slider.value=0.0;
                    slider.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
                }
            }

            cell.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            [bgview addSubview:bgview1];
            [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

            /**shows who accept the alert*/
            if(![allAlertStatus[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {
                UIButton *b1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                b1.frame=CGRectMake(237, 32.5, 75, 35);
                [b1 setImage:[UIImage
                              imageNamed:@"background_switch_button.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [b1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                b1.tag=indexPath.row+10;
                [cell addSubview:b1];
                slider.tag=indexPath.row+10;
                [cell addSubview:slider];
            }
            else
            {
                if(!emergencyType)
                {

                    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Accepted by:\n%@",acceptedUserNames[indexPath.row]];
                    if([str length]>32)
                        str=[[str substringToIndex:32] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
                    else if([str length]<25)
                        str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"     "];

                    UIImageView *tickImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(258, 18, 35, 20)];
                    [tickImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"]];
                    [cell addSubview:tickImage];

                    UILabel *tempLabel=[GlobalDesign createLabel:str fontFamilyName:@"FranklinGothDemiCTT" fontColor:[UIColor  colorWithRed:195/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:52/255.0 alpha:1] fontSize:15 xVal:233 yVal:45 width:85 height:50];
                    [cell addSubview:tempLabel];

                    tempLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

                    NSMutableAttributedString* content2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothDemiCTT" size:18] }];

                    [content2 setAttributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothBookCTT" size:15]} range:NSMakeRange(0,12)];

                    tempLabel.attributedText=content2;
                }
                else
                {
                    UIButton *b1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    b1.frame=CGRectMake(240, 32.5, 75, 35);
                    [b1 setImage:[UIImage
                                  imageNamed:@"ACCEPTED.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [b1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                    b1.tag=100;
                    [cell addSubview:b1];
                    [cell addSubview:slider];
                }
            }

            if(indexPath.row==noOfRows-1)
            {
                requestMode=NO;
                NSLog(@"Final values in array %d",[updatedCell count]);
            }
            NSLog(@"Added to array :%d",indexPath.row);
            [updatedCell addObject:cell];
            NSLog(@"Final values in array %d",[updatedCell count]);

            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Refresh mode mode.  %d",indexPath.row);

            if(updatedCell[indexPath.row]!=nil)
                return updatedCell[indexPath.row];
            else  {
                AlertBoxCell *cell=(AlertBoxCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InboxCell"];
                if(cell==nil)
                    cell=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlertBoxCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception);
        [[WriteLogger getWriteLogger] writeLog:moduleName sourceClass:self.nibName methodName:@"cellForRowAtIndexPath" errorMsg:exception];
    }
}
```

In the above code for example cell no:1 to 45 is printed when I scroll. After that 52 will be called. Do you have any idea?

Comment: May be, it will move to catch.

Comment: The NSLog in catch block not getting printed...

Comment: Just curious: why do you use a try/catch clause? In your scenario it may be harmful.

Answer (score 1):

One valid scenario for why cellForRowAtIndexPath would not be called is when the size or positioning of the table does not require any rows to be displayed. As you are saying when you scroll quickly, the method is not being called, so may be that's it. When you are scrolling fast, teble does not require rows 46 to 51 to be displayed. But in this case, it would not be fixed for these rows only. It depends on when you are scrolling fast. If it's fixed for 46 to 51 row numbers, then your problem is somewhere else. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Event though I don't have evidence myself that it actually will behave like that, I totally agree "that it may be the case" since it makes sense. It is dependent on the implementation of UITableView. Since it is not documented, it may or may not behave like this ;)